# Cannot set up code repository of Azure Devops for Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

I am using my personal Microsoft email account. I have an Azure DevOps account and have set up the organization and have some projects. I have created an Azure Data Factory V2 project. Both the DevOps email account and the Azure Portal email account are the same email.

When I set up a code repository for the Azure Data Factory V2 project on Azure Portal I selected the following options. However, the DevOps account is not showing up.

- Repository Type: Azure DevOps Git Azure
- Active Directory: Default
- Directory Azure DevOps Account: empty on the drop-down list ***(this is the issue I'm having)***

I followed MS documentation, went to the Azure Activity Directory, selected Enterprise applications and added this email address with the default role.

I expect to see my Azure DevOps account show up when I set up code repository on Azure Data Factory V2.

Could you please advise how to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue. The solution is to associate your Azure DevOps organization to active directory. Navigate to Organization settings => in General section => Select Azure active directory . which allows you to associate organization. Hope it helps.

Thanks
Srini